# The order returned from a vectorised function

Tags: r, vectorization

I am sending two columns of a data frame to a vectorised function.

For each row of the data frame, the function will return 3 rows.  So the total number of rows returned will be nrow(dataframe) * 3. The total columns returned will be equal to 2.

The trivial function below produces the correct set of numbers. But these numbers are returned in a peculiar order.  I guess it would be possible to get the order of these numbers in the order I desire...using some combination of base functions.  But, if possible, I want to write easy-to-understand code.

So my question is this:

Is there a better way of writing either the function (or call to the function) such that it will produce the desired result (which is commented out below) ?

```
fnVector <- function(fx, fy) {
   x1 <- fx + 1
   x2 <- fx + 2
   x3 <- fx + 3    

   y1 <- fy + 1
   y2 <- fy + 2
   y3 <- fy + 3

   vctx <- c(x1, x2, x3)
   vcty <- c(y1, y2, y3)

   #vct.pair <- c(vctx, vcty)
   vct.series <-  c(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
   return(vct.series)

}    

vct.names <- c("a", "b")
vct.x <- c(10, 20)
vct.y <- c(100, 200)
df.data <- data.frame(name = vct.names, x = vct.x, y = vct.y)
aa <- fnVector(df.data$x, df.data$y)

# desired result [nrow(dataframe) * 3, 2] (i.e. 3 x 2 )
#11, 101 (i.e. row a)
#12, 102 (i.e. row a)
#13, 103 (i.e. row a)
#21, 201 (i.e. row b)
#22, 202 (i.e. row b)
#23, 203 (i.e. row b)
```

Comment: Please review my answer.  I think you are making the problem way more complicated than it has to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to interleave your vectors, i.e. the returned x is `x1[1], x2[1], x3[1], x1[2], x2[2], x3[2], ...`

so you could:

```
vctx <- c(rbind(x1, x2, x3)) # interleaves the x2
vcty <- c(rbind(y1, y2, y3)) # interleaves the x2
```

Then return a matrix, not a vector:

```
return(cbind(vctx, vcty))
```

Giving you

```
fnVector <- function(fx, fy) {
   x1 <- fx + 1
   x2 <- fx + 2
   x3 <- fx + 3    

   y1 <- fy + 1
   y2 <- fy + 2
   y3 <- fy + 3

   vctx <- c(rbind(x1, x2, x3)) # interleaves the x2
   vcty <- c(rbind(y1, y2, y3)) # interleaves the x2

   return(cbind(vctx, vcty))
}
fnVector(df.data$x, df.data$y)
#      vctx vcty
# [1,]   11  101
# [2,]   12  102
# [3,]   13  103
# [4,]   21  201
# [5,]   22  202
# [6,]   23  203
```

You may want to think about also retaining the `name` column.

---

I don't know if this is adaptable to your specific application or not (I understand you have simplified your `fnVector` for the purposes of this question), but you might want to investigate `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df.data, .(name), summarize,
      vctx = x + 1:3,
      vcty = y + 1:3)
#   name vctx vcty
# 1    a   11  101
# 2    a   12  102
# 3    a   13  103
# 4    b   21  201
# 5    b   22  202
# 6    b   23  203
```

The `ddply(df.data, .(name),` says "for each unique value in `df.data$name`", the `summarize` says "call the `summarize` function", then the two named arguments `vctx=..` and `vcty=..`. create the output 3 rows for each of these columns (for us, `x+1:3` and `y+1:3`, but for your application, probably something more complex).

Comment: Thanks very much. The `code`vctx <- c(rbind(x1, x2, x3))`code` did the trick! Thanks for your comments about `code`ddply()`code`. I cannot use this library where I work. We are using`code` dply()`code` but I guess the principle would be the same. I am curious @peter how summarize() would produce more rows that what I receives (I thought as an aggregation operation it does things in reverse). Thanks again.

Comment: @markthekoala - yeah, summarize is supposed to aggregate, but it works when you produce more rows too (since `ddply` just expects a dataframe as output of any size and `rbind` it to the other bits). If you are using `dplyr` you have to use `do` instead and it's more kludgy: `df.data %>% group_by(name) %>% do(data.frame(x=.$x + 1:3, y=.$y + 1:3))` .Again, all depends on the exact nature of your `fnVector` - you may be able to vectorise it even more e.g. what Tim has done.

Comment: This isn't the way to go for such a simple problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - yes, for the problem presented. But OP mentioned that `fnVector` was a "trivial function", i.e. a simple function that demonstrates the problem. It is not the same as their *actual* function, so I was trying to be careful to separate my answer from the specific form of `fnVector`.

Comment: I'm sure you did a solid solution given the OP, but I will leave my answer there just in case someone wants a simple way to add rows to a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function can be greatly simplified, and I also think it makes the most sense to use the custom function along with one of the `apply` functions.  Try this code:

```
fnVector <- function(x) {
    y <- rbind(x+1, x+2, x+3)
    return(y)
}

df.output <- data.frame(apply(df.data[, c("x", "y")], 2, function(x) fnVector(x)))

> df.output
   x   y
1 11 101
2 12 102
3 13 103
4 21 201
5 22 202
6 23 203
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. It works. But the function that I provided as an example is shown for illustrative purposes. The actual function is much more difficult.